Merging two arrays in PostgreSQL in different ways
Based on a previous question in stackoverflow, I have created two similar functions. One as SQL and a very similar one in PLPGSQL:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mergeArrays (a1 ANYARRAY, a2 ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS ANYARRAY AS
$$
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x)
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(a1 || a2) AS x ) s;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT;

        
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mergeArrays_plpgsql (a1 ANYARRAY, a2 ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS ANYARRAY AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x)
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST( a1 || a2 ) AS x ) s; 
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


I was expecting the same behaviour, but the first does not concat arrays if one of them is null, while the second does. Here is an example:
-- no time spent defining primary / foreign keys

CREATE TABLE userposix (
  username  varchar,
  groupname varchar,
  uoptions  varchar[]
);

CREATE TABLE groupposix (
  groupname varchar,
  goptions  varchar[]
);

INSERT INTO groupposix
  VALUES ('g1','{o1,o3}');
INSERT INTO grouposix
  VALUES ('g2');

INSERT INTO userposix
  VALUES ('u1','g1','{o1,o2}');
INSERT INTO userposix
  VALUES ('u2','g1');
INSERT INTO userposix
  VALUES ('u3','g2','{o4,o2}');

Let's take a look at the data:
SELECT username, groupname, uoptions, goptions
  FROM userposix u LEFT JOIN groupposix g USING (groupname);

 username | groupname | uoptions | goptions 
----------+-----------+----------+----------
 u2       | g1        |          | {o1,o3}
 u1       | g1        | {o1,o2}  | {o1,o3}
 u3       | g2        | {o4,o2}  | 
(3 rows)

Let's now see the diferent behaviour of each function
SELECT
    username,
    uoptions || goptions AS "just_concat",
    mergeArrays(uoptions,goptions),
    mergeArrays_plpgsql(uoptions,goptions)
  FROM userposix u
    LEFT JOIN groupposix g USING (groupname);

 username |  just_concat  | mergearrays | mergearrays_plpgsql 
----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------
 u2       | {o1,o3}       |             | {o1,o3}
 u1       | {o1,o2,o1,o3} | {o1,o2,o3}  | {o1,o2,o3}
 u3       | {o4,o2}       |             | {o2,o4}
(3 rows)

Can anybody explain me why does this happen?
The plpgsql is the behaviour I was looking for, and more similar to direct SQL solution:
SELECT
    username,
    uoptions || goptions AS "just_concat",
    (select array_agg(x order by x)
       from (select distinct unnest(uoptions||goptions)as x) foo )
  FROM userposix u
    LEFT JOIN groupposix g USING (groupname);

 username |  just_concat  | array_agg  
----------+---------------+------------
 u2       | {o1,o3}       | {o1,o3}
 u1       | {o1,o2,o1,o3} | {o1,o2,o3}
 u3       | {o4,o2}       | {o2,o4}
(3 rows)


The first function is STRICT, the second is not. That changes the behavior of how to handle a null

You are right. Thak you.

As Frank Heikens has commented, a STRICT function (like the first one), changes the behaviour of how to handle a null as an argument in a function.
As the official documentation describes:

RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT or STRICT indicates that the function always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null.
If this parameter is specified, the function is not executed when
there are null arguments; instead a null result is assumed
automatically.

So the simplier function I was looking for is (SQL without STRICT):
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mergeArrays (a1 ANYARRAY, a2 ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS ANYARRAY AS
$$
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x)
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(a1 || a2) AS x ) s;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

Thanks Frank.
